# How to use jsdom.jQueryify with jasmine-node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bdd, jasmine, jsdom

Is it possible to user jasmine-node with the jQueryify feature of jsdom? What I'm trying to do is use NodeJS to test some JavaScript that depends on the presence of the DOM.

Here is a reduced case of what I tried. When I run the script, jasmine-node recognizes the spec, but doesn't run the `expect()`:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    window = jsdom.createWindow(),
    jasmine = require('jasmine-node')

describe("jQueryify", function() {
    it('should run the test!', function () {
        jsdom.jQueryify(window, function (window, jquery) {
            expect(1).toEqual(1)
        })
    })
})
```

Alternately, is there a different/better way to test stuff in NodeJS that assumes a browser-like environment?

Answer (score 2):

OK, based on one [this answer to a semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101673/what-are-the-use-cases-of-jsdom/6130263#6130263), I was able to get the `expect()` to execute. I guess the answer to my question is not to use the built-in jQueryify function, but to pull in jQuery 'manually'.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    window = require('jsdom').jsdom('<html><head></head><body></body></html>').createWindow(),
    script = window.document.createElement('script'),
    jasmine = require('jasmine-node')

describe("jQueryify", function() {
    it('should run the test!', function () {
        script.src = './path/to/jquery.js'
        script.onload = function () {
            expect(typeof window.$).toEqual('function')
            asyncSpecDone()
        }
        window.document.head.appendChild(script)
        asyncSpecWait()
    })
})
```