# How do you parse DOM nodes using Grunt.js & Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, gruntjs, jasmine

I am using Grunt.js & Jasmine to do automated testing.
One of my tests is supposed to check that a script has correctly created and appended an HTML node.

```
it('should create <div></div>', function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
    expect(element.constructor()).toEqual(HTMLDivElement);
});
```

But when I run the test I just get an error back.

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.appendChild') in file:///foo.js (line 14) (1)
```

gruntfile.js:

```
jasmine : {
    myTest: {
      src: '../js/*.js',
        options: {
          specs:['tests/*.js'],
          display: 'full',
          summary: true,
          junit: {
            path: 'logs',
            consolidate: true
          }
        }
    }
}
```

package.json (partial):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-jslint": "~1.1.8",
    "grunt-jsdoc": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.6.3",
    "phantomjs": "1.8.2-0"
}
```

Comment: Well, I got the Tumbleweed award...
(dance)

Comment: Does anyone know? Am I missing some vital info to explain what I'm trying to do?
Searching on the internet turns up several mentions of headless, but no example showing how that works...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jsdom.jQueryify with jasmine-node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220889/how-to-use-jsdom-jqueryify-with-jasmine-node)

Comment: with the minor exception that I didn't mention jQuery.